# Magento - caching calls to Mage

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have in my header, several calls to Mage to get the catalog categoery model and get a collection of items.

My problem is, this seems to make my page twice as slow, even with HTML Block caching turned on in the admin.

What I thought I could, was by using:

> $cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache');

and thus could cache the calls to Mage, such as:

```
      $newCarCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(11)->getProductCollection()->setPageSize(6); 
      $newCarCollection = $newCarCollection->getItems(); 
      $cache = Mage::getSingleton('core/cache'); 
      $cache->save($newCarCollection, "car_collection", array("car_cache"), 140);
      $cache->load("car_collection");
```

This simply doesn't work.

Is this even possible to do, or have I just made it up?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime'    => 3600,
        'cache_tags'        => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG, Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block caching needs to be enabled for each block type, as well as the option in admin.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/development/block_cache_and_html_ouput

If that works it'll be more efficient than caching product objects.

Comment: @clockworkgeek But, I have these calls in my header.phtml file. How would I cache them in this case? Uncommenting out the calls, there are roughly 3 calls to Mage::getModel and then on each of these is a foreach loop to get the products in the category

Comment: @terrid25 - You could make your own block that is included in the header block. The header cannot usually be cached because it has contents that change, like the cart and login/logout links. Your block's output could be cached when the rest of the header is not.

Comment: How would I do that though? I see the block for the header in page.xml Would I need to create a new block, i.e. nav.phtml and then add that to the page.xml file?

Comment: Ok, so I've created a new block named Nav.php in app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block and also the nav.phtml in app/design/frontend/../templates/page/html I've add the block to my 2columns.phtml template and all seems to work. Can I now use things like <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('nav') ?> can I now put caching into my Nav.php block?

Comment: Yes. If you now specify the cache tags and key for your new Nav block it should work. You can check by putting a `Mage::log(__FILE__)` somewhere in your 'nav.phtml' file and watching the 'var/log/system.log' file. It should show an entry on the first visit but not on any subsequent visit. (Fingers crossed!)

Comment: @clockworkgeek Ok am i putting the caching in the constructor, or as separate methods?

Comment: This is because in my Nav.php block, I have:     function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/nav.phtml');
    }

Comment: Magento likes to make this bit confusing, there are two constructors. The first is with two underscores (which you have) and that eventually calls the other (with one underscore). In this case I don't think it matters which you use, both are called before the `_toHtml` method which is when the cache is checked.

Comment: @clockworkgeek Ok, so I can put the caching in my constructor. My only concern is that I have the calls in the nav.phtml to Mage, which don't seem to get cached. I don't have a _toHtml method either, just the constructor. See my updated answer:

Comment: toHtml is inherited from Mage_Core_Block_Abstract so you don't need to worry about that detail.

Comment: @clockworkgeek how about my constructor above, does that look ok?